# ng-bind-html not working with my $scope.variable

Tags: html, angularjs, sanitize, ng-bind-html

I am trying to add something like dynamic HTML using ng-bind-html but its not working with $scope variable

Here is my  Angular code

1)My controller

```
$scope.name = "Parshuram"
$scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div>{{name}}</div>");
```

Also that my string is dynamic

```
"<div><table class=" + "\"table table - bordered table - responsive table - hover add - lineheight table_scroll\"" + "><thead><tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr ng-repeat=" + "\"tr in dyna\"" + "><td>{{tr.name}}</td><td>{{tr.age}}</td></tr></tbody></table></div>"
```

So i cant replace every variable with $scope

2)- My HTML

```
<div ng-app="mymodule" ng-controller="myModuleController">
    <div ng-bind-html="thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml"></div>
</div>
```

I got this output

```
{{name}}
```

My expected output is

```
Parshuram
```

Please can anyone help i am stuck at this point,does that $sce does not bind scope variable?? ..

Comment: If you're getting that html from a server, and can make the server return a response which is exactly the html you want, then just use `ng-include="'//theserver/somepage'"` and that will fetch the html and include it as a template.

Comment: can you explain that in detail this is my service with returns html string

Comment: $http.get('http://localhost:22475/api/mymodule').then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);});

Comment: Try this: `$scope.template = '//localhost:22475/api/mymodule';` then in the html `<div ng-include="template"></div>`

Comment: @Duncan its so simple thanku for that,it worked..One question can i give a query parameter to that API??? //localhost:22475/api/mymodule?dt = 4

Comment: @Duncan Wow sir it worked i am using this right now,can you please tell me the difference between $http request and this request?

Comment: The url can include parameters, and it's just angular expression so you can set it from your controller. `$http` lets you fetch the data and use it in your code, ng-include just fetches html into the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created a working plnkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/uOdbHjv1B7fr0Ra1kXI3?p=preview

the problem is that ng-bind-html is not bound to the scope.
you should manually compile the content.

a valid and reusable solution should be creating a directive, whitout using any external modules.

```
function compileTemplate($compile, $parse){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
            function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }    
            scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
                $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  
             });
        }
    }
  }




<div ng-app="mymodule" ng-controller="myModuleController">
    <div ng-bind-html="thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml" compile-template></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: No this is also not working for me still giving {{name}}

Comment: i've added a working plnkr in my answer starting from your code.

Comment: Wowww thanku it worked perfectly,i think i was making mistake in directive,but thanku you very much..

Comment: fantastic answer, but what if the html you are binding to has a directive in it, is there an easy way to do this recursively?  e.g. <div ng-bind-html="myhtml"> where myhtml = "<my-directive></my-directive>" produces <div><my-directive></my-directive></div> rather than the inner directive being compiled and correctly rendered

Comment: recursive possible simply by changing the maxPriority value.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind-html` does what it says on the tin: it binds html. It doesn't bind angular template code into your dom.

You need to do this instead:

```
$scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = 
    $sce.trustAsHtml("<div>"+$sanitize(name)+"</div>");
```

To do this you'll want to include the module `ngSanitize` from the javascript `angular-sanitize.js`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

If you want to insert some html that includes angular directives then you should write your own custom directive to do it.

Comment: Do i need to add sanitize.min.js for it??

Comment: You would need angular-sanitize, but really you should consider whether you can do what you need with a custom directive (or component) instead.

Comment: I am sending a string from my server,so cant prefer a directive

Answer (score 0):

In your html just use
    
        {{name}}
    
The {{var}} notation is to be used in the HTML code to evaluate that variable.

Comment: No i dont want to use in html my HTML string is coming from my server and i want to bind it with html

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
$scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div ng-bind="name"></div>');
```

Comment: my question is how i can bind my scope variable with $sce html-bind

Comment: please check my question i want my scope variable to bind because i am sending a string from my server and binding it with html , if any other way so that i can send some string and change my name as scope variable changes but i want to send string html

Comment: I am having difficulties reading you I'm sorry, I edited my question to cope with your needs, see the last part of it.

Comment: I completely edited my question now, this way we are on the same page !

Comment: Can you then try `$scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<span ng-bind="name"></span>');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I make another answer.

If you have

```
$scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div>{{name}}</div>");
```

Then you can do

```
var str = "<div>{{name}}</div>";
var output = str.replace('{{name}}', $scope.name);
```

It seems to be the only option.

Comment: Sorry i cant use replace here my html string can be anything suppose for eg this "<div><table class=" + "\"table table - bordered table - responsive table - hover add - lineheight table_scroll\"" + "><thead><tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr ng-repeat=" + "\"tr in dyna\"" + "><td>{{tr.name}}</td><td>{{tr.age}}</td></tr></tbody></table></div>  so i cant replace every variable