# Watch ng-model in ng-bind-html using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, watch, angularjs-ng-model, ng-bind-html

Here is my Markup

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <p ng-bind-html="myText|unsafe"></p>
</div>
```

I am using this code

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "My name is: <h1>{{name}}</h1>";
    $scope.name="Habib";
});
app.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

**Output:**

> My name is: {{}}

**Desired Output:**

> My name is: Habib

I want it should also reflect value from textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

The reason you are having issues with getting `$scope.name` bound is because `ng-bind-html` does not bind that html to the current scope. You can use a directive to fix this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40789552/6869691) is an answer that fixes your issue.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/a7NXO6hTYdM9WL8fc3ei?p=preview) is a plunker that adds the directive and shows the behavior you are looking for.

Here is the directive that was added that fixes your issue:

```
app.directive('compileTemplate', function($compile, $parse){
   return {
       link: function(scope, element, attr){
           var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
           function getStringValue() {
                return (parsed(scope) || '').toString();
           }

            // Recompile if the template changes
            scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
                // The -9999 makes it skip directives
                // so that we do not recompile ourselves
                $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  
            });
        }
    }
});
```

---

You need to declare `$scope.name="Habib"` before the `myText` scope variable.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.name="Habib";
    $scope.myText = "My name is: <h1>{{name}}</h1>";
});
app.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
   };
});
```

Comment: Ok, But how the value of input will reflect

Comment: It should update when you edit the text in input. You may need to use `$scope.$apply() ` in your controller to trigger a digest cycle to update the variable.

Comment: @habib I edited my initial answer and found the reason you are having an issue.

Comment: That's pretty nice!, Thanks