# AngularJS ng-bind-html not working with expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to evaluate an expression in ng-bind-html but it's not working. If anyone knows workaround for this, please help.

The code below is showing nothing.

```
<h5 ng-bind-html="{{feedType ==='popularProducts' ? displayedProduct.title : displayedProduct.name}}"></h5>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console and are you sure ng-bind-html will evaluate expression in {{}} ?  I have tried in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L4zqv6fg/1/  and {{}} itself is not getting evaluated.. Can you please update the fiddle with more info about controller details or why you are using ng-bind-html here?

Comment: {{}} is not working with ng-bind-html tag. That's why I'm asking for workaround. I'm using ng-bind-html because the content contains some symbol codes which is converted by html like registered/TM symbol code.

Comment: Got it. Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788937/ng-bind-html-not-working-with-my-scope-variable if this can help?

Comment: No I'm not supposed to add any kind of controller. All I can do is change in the tag with some angularjs directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ngBindHtml` directive expects the attribute value as an expression so there is no need for the `{{}}` interpolation. Simply remove those braces so that you’re passing your expression directly to the directive.

Working Syntax:

```
<h5 ng-bind-html="feedType === 'popularProducts' ? displayedProduct.title : displayedProduct.name"></h5>
```

Applicable AngularJS [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml#ngBindHtml-arguments)