# AngularJS two way data binding not working after my html added new inner html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a html

```
<div id="doc1"></div>
```

after that I add add new html inside id "doc1"

```
document.getElementById("doc1").innerHTML = '<div id="doc2">{{ value }}</div>';
```

accurately there should be

```
<div id="doc1"><div id="doc2">{{ value }}</div></div>
```

but {{ value }} not working to bind

this my JS code

```
(function () {
    angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', myController);

    function myController($scope){
      Initial();
    
      function Initial(){
         document.getElementById("doc1").innerHTML = "<div id="doc2">{{ value }}</div>";
         $scope.value = "Hi There";
      }
    }
}) ();
```

Comment: `document.getElementById()` and `.innerHTML` have _nothing_ to do in an Angular app. It is out of "Angular's world". Selecting elements by ID and adding text to them is not how Angular works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788937/ng-bind-html-not-working-with-my-scope-variable

Comment: I see, thankyou for your answer Nitheesh

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ngBindHtml` [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

in template

```
<div id="doc1" ng-bind-html="htmlData"></div>
```

in controller

```
$scope.htmlData = "<div id="doc2">{{ value }}</div>";
$scope.value = "Hi There";
```

Comment: I do follower you answer but result still same, {{ value }} not bind